# Method for solving differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for help with what method to solve this ordinary differential equation with,

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=x+y $$

I know it's not separation of variables since it's not in the form of

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=f (y)g (x) $$

Answer (score 2):

Let us first try a polynomial solution. As the RHS has a first order term ($x$), a linear solution of the form $y_1=ax+b$ might do. We have

$$(ax+b)'=a=x+(ax+b),$$

which is fulfilled with $a=b=-1$, hence $y_1=-x-1$.

Now if we subtract memberwise

$$y'=x+y$$ and
$$y'_1=x+y_1$$ we eliminate $x$ and get

$$(y-y_1)'=y-y_1$$ or $$y'_2=y_2$$ which is separable.

Now

$$\frac{y'_2}{y_2}=1,\\\log y_2=x+c,\\y_2=ce^x$$ and

$$y=y_1+y_2=-x-1+ce^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you write

$$y'-y = x$$

and multiply by $e^{-x}$, you get

$$e^{-x}y'-e^{-x}y = e^{-x}x.$$

The left side is the product rule for $e^{-x}y$, so we have

$$\left(e^{-x}y\right)' =  e^{-x}x .$$

Integrate both sides and then multiply through by $e^x.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The differential equation is a linear differential equation with constant coefficients.

First, solve: $$\dfrac{dy_h}{dx}=y_h$$ and then determine the particular solution by the ansatz $y_p=ax+b$ or use variation of paramters ansatz $y_p(x)=c(x)y_h(x)$ and determine $c(x)$. The general solution is given by

$$y = y_h+y_p.$$